# Response.readEntity(String.class) failing to read the response

Tags: java, maven, jax-rs, httpresponse, rest

Recently I started facing an issue all of a sudden for read entity API.
I have attached the pom.xml and the code used could someone please help me find the issue here,
code that is reading the response

```
Response serverResponse = executeRequest(httpPost, log);
String responseData = serverResponse.readEntity(String.class);
```

Error that I was getting is

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method not supported on an outbound message.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.OutboundJaxrsResponse.readEntity(OutboundJaxrsResponse.java:144)
```

pom.xml

```
 <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.mfp/adapter-maven-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.mfp</groupId>
            <artifactId>adapter-maven-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.2018071507</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.7</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.mfp/mfp-java-token-validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.mfp</groupId>
            <artifactId>mfp-java-token-validator</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.2017020112</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.mfp/mfp-security-checks-base -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.mfp</groupId>
            <artifactId>mfp-security-checks-base</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.2018030404</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

error message:

nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax/ws/rs/core/Response.readEntity(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;, status=500

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this problem by using

```
String responseData = serverResponse.getEntity().toString();
```

instead of

```
String responseData = serverResponse.readEntity(String.class);
```

It has something to do with the way we form the response. I was manipulating response as

```
 Response.ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = Response
                .status(serverResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode())               
                .entity(responseData != null && !responseData.isEmpty() ? responseData : "{}");
```

and then I was using `String responseData = serverResponse.readEntity(String.class);` when I changed readEntity to getEntity it worked fine for me.